# Unchecked Cast error while passing an arraylist from one activity to another using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

```
public class Checkout extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ekdum_final_order_names = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent = getIntent();

     public ArrayList<Integer> intArray_id_selected;
    public ArrayList<Integer> intArray_no;
    Map<Integer ,String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);

        intArray_no = (ArrayList<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("int_array_no");
        intArray_id_selected = (ArrayList<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("int_array_id");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),intArray_id_selected.get(0)+"  "+ intArray_no.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is the class which receives the arraylists from antoher class using intent. I get an unchecked cast warning: `"Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<android.app.Fragment>'" and due to this i get java null pointer exception.` This iis the logcat :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.io.Serializable
>   android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.gandhjee.pantry_order.Checkout.onCreate(Checkout.java:39)

Please help me find my mistake. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: This issue seems to be independent of the casting exception. Specifically, the NPE is indicating that, in the assignments of `intArray_no` and/or `intArray_id_selected`, `intent` is null, so you obviously aren't going to be able to call `getSerializableExtra(String)` on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: post the code that you use to put the extras into the `Intent`.

Comment: You cant put `getIntent` outside of `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `getIntent()` inside `onCreate()`.
As Intent get available after `onCreate()`, there is `Intent` present before `onCreate()`.

Try this:

```
public class Checkout extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ekdum_final_order_names = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> intArray_id_selected;
    public ArrayList<Integer> intArray_no;
    Map<Integer ,String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intArray_no = (ArrayList<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("int_array_no");
        intArray_id_selected = (ArrayList<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("int_array_id");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),intArray_id_selected.get(0)+"  "+ intArray_no.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

If this doesn't work try to create your array and clone it with the intent data as:

```
intArray_no = new ArrayList<Integer>((Integer)intent.getSerializableExtra("int_array_no");
```